# Centering img horizontally and vertically with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I am trying to center this brand logo vertically and horizontally on the whole page with JQuery. It **does work** on browser resize but **not initially**. **Notice this code resizes the image to fit the page.** I tried $(window) and $(document) JS is:

```
$(function() {
    var resizeToFit = function(){
        var $this = $(document);
        var imgw = $("#overlay-logo img").width();
        var pw = $this.width();
        var $overlaylogo = $("#overlay-logo img");
        $overlaylogo.css("width", pw - 100);
        var left = (pw / 2) - (imgw / 2);
        $overlaylogo.css('margin-left',left);
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        resizeToFit();
    });
    resizeToFit();
});
```

CSS:

```
#overlay-logo{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
z-index: 999999;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay-logo">
  <img src="img/overlay.png" alt="overlay" />
</div>
```

Comment: maybe the first run is before the image itself has loaded. Try adding a `load` listener on the image.

Comment: also, `function(){ resizeToFit(); }` is superfluous here; just send `resizeToFit` directly.

Comment: Add the width / height attributes on your <img> tag with the dimensions of your image. The width / height calculation will be correct on the first 'run'.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do this with just straight css.

```
#overlay-logo{    
    height:99%;
    width:99%;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GheZd/

**EDIT**
Just make your height and width 99% then. You can put apply this style directly to the image...you don't necessarily need the div.

Comment: I need it to resize the image to fit the page. The jQuery I wrote current does that. I edited my answer to show that.